# macOS Mojave 10.14.2 update failure

Tags: macos, macos-mojave

Through the 10.14.2 update process at my company I observed that about 10% of computers encountered an issue during the update that required us to wipe the disk in recovery mode before any macOS installation would be successful.

The update fails during one of its restarts back to the login screen. After logging in a progress bar appears under the screen before it transitions to a Setup Assistant-style screen. A banner immediately appears with a notice stating that "Critical software update is missing and must be installed before you can use your computer." With options to Try Again (never works) or Shut Down. After choosing shut down the logon screen -> installation loop continues.

We were able to put the devices into Safe Mode and recover data that way before wiping and reinstalling the OS. However, this was a fairly common issue within my user pool that was not observed anywhere else (from what I can find based on moderately intense Googling and other searches).

Has anyone else encountered this problem?

Many thanks for your assistance!